# Style not view when publish MVC3 to virtual directory IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, publish

When I publish web MVC3 to a virtual directory style of site not view.
Link css file incorrect: /virtual directory/content/abc.css instead of /content/abc.css

Comment: how have you referenced your css file in your view?

Comment: Yes, i refenced <link href="../../../../Content/Manager/SiteManager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. If edit to <link href="../../../../virtual directory/Content/Manager/SiteManager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<link href="../../../../Content/Manager/SiteManager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Manager/SiteManager.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`~` gives you the root.

`UrlHelper.Content` converts virtual to the correct absolute path regardless of the directory structure that you have on dev, stage, prod,...